# What is an abstract data type in object oriented programming?

Tags: oop, object, abstract-data-type

What is an abstract data type in object oriented programming? I've gone through the wiki for this topic, but I am still unclear about it. Could someone clarify?

Comment: possible duplicate of [characteristics of the abstract class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849056/characteristics-of-the-abstract-class)

Comment: @MarkSeemann I read it twenty years ago mate. ADT is not an OO concept. Most modern languages use generic programming instead to implement them.

Comment: Ans: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/288504/114794

Comment: The best simple definition I found is from Cracking the Coding Interview by Gayle L.M.: "An abstract data type is defined by its behavior (its operations). The underlying implementation can vary. You could implement a priority queue with an array or a min (or max) heap (or many other data structures)." Some Common Abstract Data Types (ADTs): List, Set, Graph, Stack, Queue, Priority queue, etc.

Comment: ADT is at the core of OOP Abstraction principle, which should be supplemented by Polymorphism and Inheritance. One might say that ADT (Abstraction) is at the very base of OOP and the rest of the principles stem from it to supplement it.

Answer (score 63):

An *abstract class* is a generalization concept. It is a class you invent to only use as a base class for inheritance but not to instantiate objects from.

And *abstract datatype*  ([ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)) is not necessarily an OOP concept. It is an older term to describe the concepts of for example Stack and Queue in terms of their functionality, without describing the implementation.

Comment: The first few answers simply discussed the abstract keyword of java, which doesn't define a data type per se. Looking up "abstract data type" I got http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type. Henk identifies both of these concepts. It is not obvious that the OP's question is well posed.

Answer (score 47):

There is a difference between an "**abstract data type**" and an "**abstract class**".

An **abstract class** is one that may not have definitions for all the methods it defines. You therefore cannot directly instantiate an abstract class. You have to create a subclass and then instantiate that.

An **abstract data type** is a **model** of a certain kind of data structure e.g. a **Stack**. A Stack has push() and pop() operations and that have well-defined behaviour.

The abstract data type (ADT) itself **refers to this model, not any particular implementation in any particular programming language or paradigm**. You could implement a Stack in an object-oriented language, but you could also implement it in a functional programming language.

ADTs allow discussion about the properties of Stacks, Queues etc that hold for all correct implementations of the ADT.

Comment: didn't understood the third point very much; more confused with this quote "The abstract data type (ADT) itself refers to this model, not any particular implementation in any particular programming language or paradigm"

Comment: ADTs are also the base for "abstract test suites", following [Meyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Oriented_Software_Construction)'s idea that "an object/module/(sub-)system is defined by what you can do with it".

Comment: I would add the idea that what paradigm(s) is(are) implemented by the programming language doesn't matter, in the time when this term was more popular languages never skewed in favor of a paradigm as they do today, all languages considered to be multiparadigm, our popular languages are multiparadigm.

I would say ADTs are very similar to if not the same thing as Duck Typing.

Answer (score 9):

Well, it's all about ***abstraction***. Abstraction is particularly useful in programming. The main advantage is ability to hide realization details. You hide it inside one modules (so-called "server modules") and provide some public interface for other modules (so-called "client modules"). And now we have three different possibilities:

### Server module can supply an *abstract data structure (ADS)* itself.

In that case it contains ADS entity itself. The public interface consists of some procedures (and maybe some constants).

Interface of server module (stack_ads.h):

```
#ifndef STACK_ADS
#define STACK_ADS

const int capacity = 10;

void clear();
int size();
int pop();
void push(int value);

#endif STACK_ADS
```

Implementation (stack_ads.cpp):

```
#include "stack_ads.h"

int items[capacity];
int top = -1;

void clear()
{
  top = -1;
}

int size()
{
  return top + 1;
}

int pop()
{
  top -= 1;
  return items[top + 1];
}

void push(int value)
{
  top += 1;
  items[top] = value;
}
```

In the client module (main.cpp) we import server module and use data structure directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack_ads.h"

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) 
{
  push(1);
  push(2);
  push(3);

  std::cout << pop() << std::endl;
  std::cout << pop() << std::endl;
  std::cout << pop() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

### Server module can supply an *abstract data type (ADT)* in the form of struct/record.

In client module we can declare variables to be of that type. Because a module is free to declare more than one variable to be of the exported type, it can have more than one data structure. Each abstract data structure is variable of abstract data type.

Interface (stack_adt.h):

```
#ifndef STACK_ADT
#define STACK_ADT

const int capacity = 10;

typedef struct
{
  int items[capacity];
  int top;
} StackADT;

void clear(StackADT* stack);
int size(StackADT* stack);
int pop(StackADT* stack);
void push(StackADT* stack, int value);  

#endif STACK_ADT
```

Implementation (stack_adt.cpp):

```
#include "stack_adt.h"

void clear(StackADT* stack)
{
  stack->top = -1;
}

int size(StackADT* stack)
{
  return stack->top + 1;
}

int pop(StackADT* stack)
{
  stack->top -= 1;
  return stack->items[stack->top + 1];
}

void push(StackADT* stack, int value)
{
  stack->top += 1;
  stack->items[stack->top] = value;
}
```

Client module:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack_adt.h"

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) 
{
  StackADT stack1;
  StackADT stack2;
  stack1.top = -1;
  stack2.top = -1;

  push(&stack1, 1);
  push(&stack1, 2);
  push(&stack1, 3);

  std::cout << pop(&stack1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << pop(&stack1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << pop(&stack1) << std::endl;

  push(&stack2, 10);
  push(&stack2, 20);
  push(&stack2, 30);

  std::cout << pop(&stack2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << pop(&stack2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << pop(&stack2) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

### Finally the server module can supply an *abstract data type (ADT)* in the form of *class*.

If our language support OOP we can describe ADT by means of classes. And once again in client module we can declare variables to be of that type. In object-oriented terminology, the type is called a *class*, and the variable with that type is called an *object*.

Server module interface (Stack.h):

```
#ifndef STACK
#define STACK

const int capacity = 10;

class Stack
{
public:
  Stack();
  void clear();
  int size();
  int pop();
  void push(int value);
private:
  int items[capacity];
  int top;
};

#endif STACK
```

Implementation (Stack.cpp):

```
#include "Stack.h"

Stack::Stack()
{
  this->top = -1;
}

void Stack::clear()
{
  this->top = -1;
}

int Stack::size()
{
  return this->top + 1;
}

int Stack::pop()
{
  this->top -= 1;
  return this->items[this->top + 1];
}

void Stack::push(int value)
{
  this->top += 1;
  this->items[this->top] = value;
}
```

The differences between two last options are:

- Terminological mentioned above (type <-> class, variable <-> object).
- In the non-class ADT, the formal parameter list of every procedure must include a variable s of type Stack. In the stack class, the specification of the data structure s is not included with the other formal parameters following the name of the procedure, but
  stands alone enclosed in parentheses before the name of the procedure. Using Smalltalk terminology formal parameter before the procedure name is called the ***receiver***.
- The location of the procedures. In the non-class ADT, the procedures are located outside the Stack struct. In the class, the procedures are located within the class. In object-oriented terminology, procedures that have receivers, and are therefore contained within a class type, are called ***methods***.

Client code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) 
{
  Stack stack1;
  Stack stack2;

  stack1.push(1);
  stack1.push(2);
  stack1.push(3);

  std::cout << stack1.pop() << std::endl;
  std::cout << stack1.pop() << std::endl;
  std::cout << stack1.pop() << std::endl;

  stack2.push(10);
  stack2.push(20);
  stack2.push(30);

  std::cout << stack2.pop() << std::endl;
  std::cout << stack2.pop() << std::endl;
  std::cout << stack2.pop() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

An Abstract Data Type (ADT) is a mathematical model of a type of data. It describes operations that can be performed on the data and the mathematical definition of those operations using equations.

For example, you can model the behaviour of a stack of numbers, perfectly abstractly using operations such as pop(), push(), top() and maybe a constant symbol representing the empty stack.

For example here are some equations that could form part of the definition of a stack of numbers:

```
pop(empty) = empty  // silently ignores popping an empty stack
pop(push(N,S)) = S  // i.e. pop removes the top element of push(N,S)
top(push(N,S)) = N  // return topmost element of the stack without changing the stack
```

An abstract data type isn't at all the same thing as a class in an object model - although they bare some similarities.

Here are the names of the important concepts: initial algebra semantics, isomorphism, quotients, congruences

The point of an abstract data type is to understand the behaviour of a whole class of equivalent type representations using equations and some fancy mathematics that demonstrates that each implementation is "isomorphic" - i.e. that both implementations are exactly equivalent as far as the observable behaviour is concerned.

The wikipedia entry on this is pretty good: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type

Here are some good (but very theoretical) course notes that pin down what an ADT is http://www-compsci.swan.ac.uk/~csulrich/ftp/adt/adt.pdf

Although superficially similar to the concept of a "class" in some object-oriented programming languages, a "class" is not an ADT, but a class can be used to implement a specific ADT.

In general the ADT concept is probably more applicable to functional programming than object-oriented programming because not all object-oriented programming languages have classes and ADT-style thinking produces less effective OO designs.

- Here's a paper that demonstrates the problems of thinking in terms of ADTs in an OO language: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=74885
- Basically the paper shows that the "class" that you use to implement an ADT ends up covered with lots of tiny little methods (that look like the basis of ADT equations) rather than having a few powerful, high-abstraction methods.

Comment: nonsense, for all practical purposes ADT is duck typing, you define a type by its operations, not by a tag as you do in nominal typing or by the structure of data, the whole point is "implementation doesn't matter" In typed OO languages you use an Interface. In dynamic typing is just duck typing.

Comment: What precisely is nonsense there? "for all practical purposes" isn't a definition. Does that mean "I can't be bothered to pick apart what you said".

Comment: @kisai - Did you by any chance study a course at university called "Abstract Data Types"? Don't think so, so keep your value judgements to yourself.

Comment: tbh that comment is from a year ago, I don't even remember why I made it, but yes I did studied ADTs in college and beyond. And for practical purposes it means when you do the implementation in code with a specific programming language, it should've been obvious for you.

Comment: "If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck", walking and quacking are operations, "like a duck" summarizes the properties it has to satisfy, and "for practical purposes" means for practical purposes, don't be rigorous in the interpretation. And don't get offended because that is the reason for your reply snowflake.

Comment: @kisai Okay, got it, not using enough ducks.

Answer (score 6):

### Definition:

Roughly speaking, **Abstract Data Type** (ADT) is a way of looking at a data structure: *focusing on what it does and ignoring how it does* its job.

Abstract data types are defined primarily by their interface: the permissible operations that can be carried out on them. The underlying mechanism used to
implement them is typically not visible to their user.

---

### Examples:

`Stack`, `Queue` and `PriorityQueue` are some of the examples of the ADTs, they are more abstract than say arrays, linked lists and many other data storage structures.

For example, the underlying mechanism for a stack, can be an `Array` or it can be a `LinkedList`. The underlying mechanism for a `PriorityQueue` can be an `Array` or a special kind of tree called a `Heap`.

---

### Code:

Here is a Java example of the abstract data type called `PriorityQueue`, implemented using the Heap:

```
class Heap {
  private Node heapArray[];
  public void insert(Node node) {...}
  public Node remove() {...}
}

class PriorityQueue {
  private Heap heap;
  public void insert(Node node) { 
    heap.insert(node);
  }
  public Node remove() {
    return heap.remove();
  }
}
```

Here you can see that the methods for the `PriorityQueue` class are simply wrapped around the methods for the underlying `Heap` class. Similarly you can use `Array` instead of `Heap` to implement the same functionality, even though in case of `Array` you'll need more code to take care of operations like insert and remove. This example should make it conceptually clear that a `PriorityQueue` is an ADT that can be implemented in a variety of ways, using heap, arrays and so on.

Although, ADTs make more sense in object oriented programming (OOP) languages, they are not limited to only OOP languages and can also be created using non-OOP languages.

---

Answer (score 3):

In the school they taught me that an ADT is just a group which contains a collection of data, and a set of operations that can be taken over this data. It just refers to the idea, and ***is not related with any ,language, implementation neither paradigm.***

Updated:
so re-reading the question, and accordingly to mi definition, an abstract data type in OOP should be a class abstraction, inherited or not, because it contains data (properties, fields, etc) and operations (methods).

regards

Answer (score 3):

Abstract is most fundamental and generalized  concept in a programming and real life.

> What is an abstract data type in object oriented programming?

ADT is a container which holds different types of objects with specifications. logical representation(i.e an interface or protocol) of the data and the operations to manipulate the component elements of the data.

Examples of ADT: List, Map, Set, Stack, Queue, Tree, Graph.

Data structures can implement one or more particular abstract data types (ADT). In java for example ArrayList, LinkedList, Stack and Vector are data structures implementation(classes) of List.

**Stack examples in real life:**

1. When a person wear **bangles** the last bangle worn is the first one to
   be removed and the first bangle would be the last to be removed.
   This follows last in first out (LIFO) principle of stack.
2. In a stack of **plates**, once can take out the plate from top or can
   keep plate at the top. The plate that was placed first would be the
   last to take out. This follows the LIFO principle of stack.
3. **Batteries** in the flashlight :- You cant remove the second battery
   unless you remove the last in. So the battery that was put in first
   would be the last one to take out. This follows the LIFO principle
   of stack.
4. **Clothes** in the trunk

**queue examples in real life**

1. A queue of people at **ticket-window**: The person who comes first gets the ticket first. The person who is coming last is getting the tickets in last. Therefore, it follows first-in-first-out (FIFO) strategy of queue.
2. **Vehicles** on toll-tax bridge: The vehicle that comes first to the toll tax booth leaves the booth first. The vehicle that comes last leaves last. Therefore, it follows first-in-first-out (FIFO) strategy of queue.
3. **Luggage** checking machine: Luggage checking machine checks the luggage first that comes first. Therefore, it follows FIFO principle of queue.
4. **Patients** waiting outside the doctor's clinic: The patient who comes first visits the doctor first, and the patient who comes last visits the doctor last. Therefore, it follows the first-in-first-out (FIFO) strategy of queue.

The above examples collected from [Source1](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/computer-science/threads/83567/stack-and-queue-real-life-examples) and [Source2](http://www.answers.com/Q/Give_at_least_5_real_life_examples_where_you_use_stack_operations)

Answer (score 2):

Take one step back from the code:

What does abstract mean? 
[Abstract](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abstract)

The gist of it is "not real, but capturing a property of real things"

You need to know this for OOP because you will be designing object universes, which requires you to think about how those objects are related.

Abstraction allows you to group some of those objects, thus organizing

1) Your thinking process
2) Your code

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until last week.

An abstract class is something that is common or something in general. You can use that class to mould it and extend it in anyway you like.

I can give you a practical example here

Take a class called animal. And it contains functions like eat, sound, move which is general that all animals do. You can extend that class to get specific like cats, dogs etc.

eg.

```
abstract class animal {

    abstract protected function eat();
    abstract protected function sound();        

}

class dogs extends animal
{
   protected function eat() {
       return "meat";
   }

   public function sound() {
       return "bow wow";
   }
}
```

hope my answer made sense to you

Answer (score 1):

1. classes uses the concept of data abstraction , known as absract data type .
2. abstract data type is an older term to describe the concepts of stack and queues in terms of their functionality without describing their implementation .

Answer (score 1):

Abstract Data Type (ADT) is a mathematical model with a collection of operations defined on that model.

Also, ADT is a data type whose behavior is defined by set of values and set of operations.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: abstract means that you can't make objects from the defined class. ex: if you have shape,square and rectangle classes, but you don't want to define any objects from shape so you will mark it as abstract...

after that if the user try to define a new object from shape, he will got compiler error..

Answer (score 0):

This is from Code Complete -Quote: 
Abstract data types form the foundation for the concept of classes.  In lanuages that support classes, you can implement each abstract data type in its own class.  Classes usually involve the additional concepts of inheritance and polymorphism.  One way of thinking of a class is as an abstract data type plus inheritance and polymorphism.

So in my opinion, Abstract data type in OO means abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

> What is an abstract data type in object oriented programming?

A Class/Abstract data type is a group of properties, and functions
(for accessing data) of anything which we may want to deal with
while solving some problem in an object oriented way.

> What is an object?

Object is an interface to a Class/Abstract data type through which we can access its properties and functions. Objects have memories associated with them used for storing data.

Answer (score 0):

ADT is a kind of data structure. Instead of describing the structure of data, it describes the operation on the data.

For example, what is a stack? Maybe a search tree or some linear data structure, but the user doesn't care. The user just cares about "last in first out" (LIFO).

Answer (score 0):

An ADT defines a set of data values and a set of operations on these values.

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](http://www.algorithmhub.online/2017/09/abstract-data-types-adts.html):

> ADT is a set of objects and operations, no where in an ADT’s definitions is there any mention of how the set of operations is implemented. Programmers who use collections only need to know how to instantiate and access data in some pre-determined manner, without concerns for the details of the collections implementations. In other words, from a user’s perspective, a collection is an abstraction, and for this reason, in computer science, some collections are referred to as abstract data types (ADTs). The user is only concern with learning its interface, or the set of operations its performs.
>
> Object such as lists, sets and graphs along with their operations can be viewed as abstract data types. ADTs are basically data types that hides its implementation details. Any part of a program that needs to perform an operation on ADT can do so by merely changing the routines that performs the ADT operations. The program that use them (ADT) will not necessarily need to know which implementation was used

Answer (score 0):

It is just like an interface. Abstract data type in a class is just used to define something i.e. Without body/implementation such as abstract methods. The body will be added where that class will be inherited.
The difference between interface and Abstract class is that we can not add a method with body in interface where as in abstract class, we can add methods/variables with body/value or make it abstract(i.e. Define there and implement where it is overrided).

Answer (score -1):

**An abstract class does not form a concrete object in the real world unlike pure implementation classes.** Abstract as the name suggestes they hold/define common behaviours of related objects that need to be reused/defined independantly in all related objects.

Take an example of Birds. If you are writing a progrm that will have something to do with the birds, then you'll first have an abstract base class as Bird and each bird deriving from the abstract base class Bird. Do note that abstract class BIRD does not represent a concrete real world object but a type of related objects that is birds!

Lets start with the class-diagram and then some code.

[alt text http://ruchitsurati.net/files/birds.png](http://ruchitsurati.net/files/birds.png)

```
public abstract class Bird
{
    protected string Name = string.Empty;
    public Bird(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public virtual void Fly()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is flying.", this.Name));
    }

    public virtual void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} cannot run.", this.Name));
    }
}

public class Parrot : Bird
{
    public Parrot() : base("parrot") { }
}

public class Sparrow : Bird
{
    public Sparrow() : base("sparrow") { }
}

public class Penguin : Bird
{
    public Penguin() : base("penguin") { }

    public override void Fly()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} cannot fly. Some birds do not fly.", this.Name));
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is running. Some birds do run.", this.Name));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Parrot p = new Parrot();
        Sparrow s = new Sparrow();
        Penguin pe = new Penguin();

        List<Bird> birds = new List<Bird>();

        birds.Add(p);
        birds.Add(s);
        birds.Add(pe);

        foreach (Bird bird in birds)
        {
            bird.Fly();
            bird.Run();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Abstract type means whose objects does not exist in real world since it does not have 
physical entity.

It acts as a base class for concrete class which has physical existance.

e.g.

```
 Shape is an abstract class whereas circle,rectangle are concrete classes.
```

Comment: **You're getting Abstract Data Type and Abstract Base Class confused here. Abstract Data Type and Abstract Base Class don't abstract the same things.** In an Abstract Data Type it means that you're abstracting away from the implmentation of a concrete thing, but in Abstract Base Class it means you've only modelled a generic part of a set of related things.