# Is there an in-built linked list node in Java libraries

Tags: java, linked-list

The LinkedList class operates over the entity and the Node is no directly exposed. Is there an in-built library which provides the traditional LinkedList interface?

PS : I see the [Apache Collections LinkedList Node](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/AbstractLinkedList.Node.html), is there one within Java librares?

Comment: A good `LinkedList` interface shouldn't expose its inner structure, so you shouldn't know there's some `Node` object on the inside.

Comment: "traditional LinkedList interface": what would that be?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the problem you're having and that this is going to solve?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267084/what-is-adt-abstract-data-type

Comment: No such class in core java, too simple and unfunctional to be implemented standalone. In Apache Collections, through, this class is also protected inner class, not intended for external use.

Comment: What are you trying to do with a node object that `LinkedList` does not support?

Answer (score 0):

Not in the standard library. You would need to find a third party library. There are many sites that will show you how to write one.

Answer (score 0):

Java collection API has [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) that is internally organized pretty muck like you desire.

But to make direct use of all these *previsous* and *next* references that each node has
you should exploit [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), getting it like that

```
iterator = linkedList.listIterator()
```

The last one has an API with a bit unintuitive behaviour, but it allows you to facilitate your code with all advantages of a linked list data structure:

- you can navigate back and forth by

  `iterator.next()
   iterator.previous()`
- you can modify the list with

  `iterator.add()
   iterator.remove()
   iterator.set()`
- you also can shift indices both ways and do the rest of things an iterator usually does, but bothways.