# Is my example a description for ADTs? (java)

Tags: java, adt, abstract-data-type

I understand that ADTs (abstract data types) hide/abstract the implementation of a method. So, an interface is an ADT, correct? So my questions are:

1. Is my example to illustrate the interface *MyStack* as an ADT and its implementation in the class *ImplementationOfMyStack*, correct?
2. If question 1 is yes, then why is there a class *Stack* in Java Libraries? My confusion is that I can instantiate the class *Stack* to use push(), pop(), peek() without coding an implementation like my example does. So, I think the class *Stack* has its implementation and is therefore a data structure and not an ADT.

```java
public interface MyStack {  
    public void push();
    public void pop();
    public void peek();
}
```

```java
public class ImplementationOfMyStack implements MyStack {

    public void push() {
        System.out.println("Code an implementation here to push a new item on top.");
        System.out.println("The implementation is a data structure e.g. linked List.");
    }

    public void pop() {
        System.out.println("Code an implementation here to pop a new item from top.");
        System.out.println("The implementation is a data structure e.g. linked List.");
    }

    public void peek() {
        System.out.println("Code an implementation here to peek a new item from top.");
        System.out.println("The implementation is a data structure e.g. linked List.");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please follow the [contribution guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question. Please do not insert images of the code. Please post your code directly with the coding tags.

Comment: @flaxel now I formatted my code accordingly. so now it is worth upvoting? ;)

Comment: Very good. I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: on a side note: public specifier in interfaces is redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes an interface is an [abstract data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267084/what-is-adt-abstract-data-type).
2. Your implementation is correct.
3. There is always a [Stack class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) in the java library. Stack is a generic data structure that represents a LIFO (last in, first out) collection of objects allowing for pushing/popping elements in constant time. (I would recommend to use the [Deque interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html). Deque defines a more complete and consistent set of LIFO operations.)