# Segmentation fault in postfix to infix C code

Tags: c, stack

I'm writing a code to convert postfix to infix. but when i try to print the stack elements to check it it's not showing any thing. in the `push` function it prints the top element, but the `display` function only shows the top element no matter what. and there is segmentation fault after the line `strcat(nn,y)`.The input i tried was `09+`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 20

char *stk[MAX], a[MAX];
int t = -1;

void push(char x[]);
void pop();
void display();

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    char *x, *y, nn[MAX];
    printf("enter expression:");
    gets(a);

    while (a[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (isdigit(a[i]))
        {
            push((char [2]){ a[i], '\0' });
        }
        else
        {
            display();
            pop();
            x = stk[t];

            pop();
            y = stk[t];

            strcpy(nn, "");
            strcat(nn, "(");
            strcat(nn, y);
            strcat(nn, (char [2]){ a[i], '\0' });
            strcat(nn, x);
            strcat(nn, ")");

            push(nn);

        }

        i++;
    }

    printf("%s", stk[0]);
}

void push(char x[])
{
    t = t + 1;
    stk[t] = x;
    printf("curtop %d:%s\n", t, stk[t]);
}

void pop()
{
    t = t - 1;
}

void display()
{
    printf("%s:%s", stk[t], stk[t - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Stop using `gets()` immediately! It is a dangerous function because you can't specify the buffer size, and it has been removed from the language. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: The problem is that you're pushing a temporary object created using the compound literal. The lifetime of that literal ends when you leave the containing `if` block, so you're causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Use `malloc()` to allocate memory for each item that you're pushing into the stack.

Comment: Every time you push `nn`, you're pushing a pointer to the same string, which you overwrite each time through the loop. Again, you need to make a copy of it so you have distinct tokens in the stack.

Comment: Show us sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I will reiterate the comments, with some references, and add a few thoughts of my own.

The first thing you should do is read [Why is the `gets` function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965) `gets` was removed from language in C11, any halfway modern tool chain should not include it:

```
example.c:5:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’; did you mean ‘fgets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

[`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is the suggested replacement. Use it.

---

Both [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal)

```
(char [2]){ a[i], '\0' }
```

occur at [block scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope), and thus have [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). This means the [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) of each object ends when their respective enclosing blocks end.

As such, you are pushing a soon-to-be [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) on to the stack.

This is an example of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

The following

```
push(nn);
```

repeatedly pushes the same pointer to the first element of `nn` on to the stack. This pointer value is always the same, and always points to the *current* contents of the array, which is constantly being changed.

Both these problems are solved by using [dynamic memory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) to create copies of the strings pushed on to the stack.

---

`nn` (infix expression buffer) has the same size as `a` (postfix expression buffer), with both being much too small.

Remembering that to store a string in a buffer, the size of the buffer must be at least the length of the string plus one (for the [null terminating byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte)).

The postfix expression

```
09+6+10*+63-/
```

has a string length of 13, which fits in `a`. With your parenthesis rules, this creates the infix expression

```
((((0+9)+6)+(1*0))/(6-3))
```

which has a string length of 25. This does not fit in `nn`, and `strcat` does nothing to guard against buffer overflows.

This would be another example of [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

---

As a quick point of design

```
pop();
x = stk[t];
```

is clumsy.

While the use of file scope variables (globals) and functions that wrap around them is a very [common way](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/stack_program_in_c.htm) data structures are introduced to beginners, you should still aim to implement something closer to an [abstract data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10267084).

`pop` should *return* the topmost element of the stack, and you as a *user* of the `pop` function should not care how that is managed, just that it behaves as expected.

```
char *x = pop();
```

The next step is to remove the file scope variables, so that more than one stack can exist in your programs at the same time.

---

Here is a cursory example program that addresses most of the issues discussed. Note that it parses input slightly differently, using [whitespace as a delimiter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok). It follows your rules for parenthesis.

It does not validate operands or the resulting expression. Operands can be longer than a single character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 256
#define SEP " \r\n"
#define STACK_INIT { 0 }
#define STACK_MAX 64

struct stack {
    size_t height;
    char *data[STACK_MAX];
};

size_t count(struct stack *s)
{
    return s->height;
}

int push(struct stack *s, const char *item)
{
    if (s->height >= STACK_MAX)
        return 0;

    char *copy = malloc(1 + strlen(item));

    if (!copy)
        return 0;

    strcpy(copy, item);
    s->data[s->height++] = copy;

    return 1;
}

char *pop(struct stack *s)
{
    return s->height ? s->data[--s->height] : NULL;
}

void free_stack(struct stack *s)
{
    char *item;

    while ((item = pop(s)))
        free(item);
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    printf("enter expression: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    if (!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) {
        if (ferror(stdin))
            perror("reading stdin");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct stack tokens = STACK_INIT;
    char *tok = strtok(buffer, SEP);

    while (tok) {
        char expr[BUF_SIZE * 2];
        /* is the first and only character an operator? */
        int is_op = strchr("+-/*", *tok) && !tok[1];

        if (is_op) {
            if (count(&tokens) < 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Operator (%c) needs two operands.\n", *tok);
                free_stack(&tokens);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            char *rhs = pop(&tokens);
            char *lhs = pop(&tokens);

            if (snprintf(expr, sizeof expr, "(%s %c %s)", lhs, *tok, rhs) >= sizeof expr)
                fprintf(stderr, "Warning: expression truncated.\n");

            free(rhs);
            free(lhs);
        }

        if (!push(&tokens, is_op ? expr : tok)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to push stack item.\n");
            free_stack(&tokens);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        tok = strtok(NULL, SEP);
    }

    for (char *s; (s = pop(&tokens)); free(s))
        printf("%s\n", s);
}
```